# How many syllables are there in the word "fire"?

Tags: syllables, diphthongs, rhoticity

We were making up Haiku, and there was some disagreement about the number of syllables in "fire."  Now granted Haiku isn't technically about syllables (see [on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_%28Japanese_prosody%29)), so technically it was a meaningless discussion.

However, I still do not know how many syllables are in "fire."

I understand an [r-colored vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-colored_vowel) might be at play.

Comment: Approximatelly 1.5

Comment: If more than one syllable means you can hyphenate the word, then "fire" has only one.  We cannot have "fi-" at the end of one line and "re" at the beginning of the next.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting question. It has made me realize I pronounce *fire* with two syllables (/faɪɚ/) as a stand-alone word and with one syllable (/faɪɹ/) as a prefix (e.g., firehouse, firebreak, fire tower, and so on).

Comment: Related Q&A: *“'One syllable' words ending in -re [e.g., 'fire']"*
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/582640/one-syllable-words-ending-in-re

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/607404/2085).

Answer (score 14):

I know nothing about Haiku, but I can tell you some general things to think about in terms of the syllable in general.

Unfortunately, the syllable is one of those concepts that is difficult to define precisely and uncontroversially in terms of its *details*, depsite it being one of the few phonological phenomena that your "average" speaker has a good degree of intiution about. What we can say is that speech appears to be organised into "syllables" which are defined by some combination of the following:

- a syllable *generally* corresponds to a peak in sonority;
- a syllable *generally* corresponds to a unit that speakers intuitively make use of in metalinguistic activities (e.g. singing or clapping one note per syllable);
- a syllable is an organisational unit: it *generally* corresponds to a vowel at its nucleus, wth which consonants at the "edges" of the same syllable are associated in some way (e.g. changes in duration can occur across the syllable as a whole unit), and in a given language you can find a relatively small number of patterns that all syllables conform to.

When considering the above factors, there are a few cases where ambiguity arises. For example, in the word "strengths", there is a peak of sonority on the "s", and it's unusual for such a complex cluster to occur, suggesting that the final "s" may constitute its own syllable. But on the other hand, few if any speakers would make two claps/taps to accompany the word "strengths", or sing it on two notes.

The word "fire" is another example where there is ambiguity, and probably speaker-to-speaker variation. On the one hand, we may conclude that it is composed of 2 syllables: one with a diphthong followed by one with a single schwa vowel. Or we may conclude that it comprises a single syllable with a triphthong ("single vowel" with three targets). One motivating argument for it being a single syllable might be the existence of alternative pronunciatons in which a single diphthong is present; a motivating argument for two syllables would be where speakers mark the word with two claps/notes, or pronounce a distinct yod ("y" sound) between the diphthong and schwa.

Comment: I don't think I disagree with a single word here. But in the end (as I think OP already knows), it's *largely a matter of choice and circumstance*. The basic concept of a *syllable* is simply too basic to be analytically useful once you get beyond *The cat sat on the mat*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : in *principle* I actually don't think that's true. For example, deciding on whether "fire" is being pronounced as 'one or two syllables' could in principle be decided, I think, on the basis of precise durational data and other phonetic cues (knowing in advance some information about the speaker's pronunciation). In *practice*, though, I agree to a large extent partly because of unavailability of such information.

Comment: In retrospect I think you're right about the continuing relevance of syllables (in principle, at least). I was quite surprised after doing a bit of googling to find that the term seems to still be considered significant (if not central) to linguistics as a formal science. But it must get a bit awkward with diphthongs/triphthongs, and "words" like *Psst* and *Sh* even in English. And I wouldn't want to think about those "clicky" North African languages! :)

Comment: Sure the syllable is still a valid concept and there is empirical evidence for it. Various applications including  speech synthesis/recognition or providing a good description of the sound system of a given language would be very difficult without a good model of the syllable. Dippthongs/triphthongs aren't per se any more of a problem than, say, consonant clusters sharing a given syllable position. "Psst" etc don't pose more of a problem than "strengths". And as far as I'm aware, to the model of the syllable, clicks are essentially consonants and don't invalidate the notion of syllable per se.

Comment: [Here's](http://encycl.opentopia.com/term/List_of_the_longest_English_words_with_one_syllable) an interesting page about "longest one-syllable words in English" that I came across when looking into "strengths".

Comment: The issue could be that the concept "syllable" includes many different criteria that don't all match - you listed a few, and @GEdgar mentioned another, namely which words you'll separate with a hyphen on different lines. Those characteristics all line up often enough that they were all grouped as defining "syllables", but they're different enough that you get many words that fit some criteria but not others. There's nothing contradictory about that. I would add a factor to how you define syllables as a result though, which is context. Which criterion is important for the question at hand ? ...

Comment: @Rozenn Keribin ... the answer in this case seems to be "none, because Haiku isn't about syllables", so the correct answer is indeed a thorough treatise on how syllables work in the English language.

Answer (score 5):

It's nothing to do with whether the letter "r" is enunciated. It's just a matter of the vowel sound, which I personally would say is a [triphthong](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/triphthong), though others might argue they don't accept that term at all, and simply call it a [diphthong](http://www.multimedia-english.com/phonetics/diphtongs.php)

For the purposes of poetry, singing, etc., it's largely a matter of choice and circumstance whether you say these sounds are one or two (or even more) syllables (and, maybe, *say/sing* them as such).

I do like this question though, because it's extended my knowledge to recognise that **choir**, for example, is in fact a [quadthong](http://www.musicedted.info/SingingBetter2/Diphthongs.html) (which after following up on @kitukwfyer's comment, I find is more often called a [tetraphthong](http://www.unilang.org/viewtopic.php?f=85&t=28555)).

Comment: This is irrelevant, but wouldn't "tetraphthong" make more sense...?

Comment: @kitukwfyer: Not only does it make more sense, I now find there are 5300 Google hits for "tetraphthong", as against only 115 for "quadthong". I will amend the answer...

Comment: It would be a ‘quadphthong’, anyway, as the Greek root for sound in this case is ‘phthong’, not ‘thong’

Comment: @nohat: Couldn't agree more. Since you've put your head over the parapet here though, I must say I would greatly value your opinion on whether it's truly valid to call *choir* a tetraphthong. Disregarding the validity of the word itself, I mean. Just insofar as we accept that there is such a thing as a one-syllable "diphthong" containing two vowel sounds.

Comment: @Fu "choir" would be at most a triphthong /kwɑɪɚ/ (US) or /kwɑɪə/, though many would argue those are two syllables (a diphthong and a monophthong).

Comment: @nohat: I get the disyllabic point (though might that depend on exactly *how* it's pronounced?), but couldn't you say the "w" adds another vowel before the "ɑɪ"? I'm not seriously arguing in favour of that, just asking if it's a tenable way of analysing the word.

Answer (score 0):

Fire has one syllable, but you are free "to play" with the words in poetry. It depends on what you want emphasized in the poem.